# Custom mailing report

Tags: civireport, mailing

I am using civicrm 4.7.7 on Drupal 7. How can I create a report of all mailings sent with CiviMail reporting the data of contacts that opened/clicked/replied the mailing?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This extension should do it ...

https://github.com/mc0e/civicrm-extendedmailingstats

Answer (score 0):

You can see these data in the mailing report: https://book.civicrm.org/user/current/email/reports-and-analysis/ for each mailing.

I don't know of a report that would aggregate  all of these stats.